# <% Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"%> Just downloads the ASP file

Tags: asp-classic, xls

I have an old site that I am trying to take down, but before I do I need to export all the data. The original site design includes an ASP file that is designed to take the data from the database tables and compile them into an excel file, but when you click on the link on the site, all it does is download the ASP file (it also only does that on IE or Edge not Chrome).

The code is below, any help making this work would be appreciated. I have done many searches and tried many suggestions but none have worked.

```
<%  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"%>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
.style1 {
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<!--#include file="../../low/connectDB.asp"-->
<!--#include file="../../low/functions.inc"-->



<body style="margin: 0">
<table style="width: 100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10"><strong>Lake of the Woods Association, Inc.</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10"><strong>Schedule of Those Who Have Passed the LOWA Boat Certification 
                Course</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10"><strong>As of <%=date%></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 150"><strong>Type</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 250"><strong>First Name</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 250"><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 250"><strong>Address</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 120"><strong>Lot</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 120"><strong>Section</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 120"><strong>Course</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 120"><strong>VA Boat Id</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 120"><strong>Minutes</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 120"><strong>Grade</strong></td>
        <td style="width: 120"><strong>Status</strong></td>
    </tr>
<%  tottimes=1
    Set DB1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        DB1.Open(lowdbstring)
            Set RS1 = DB1.Execute ("SELECT * FROM course_applicants WHERE passfail = 'pass' ORDER BY MID ASC, grade DESC, ID DESC")  
                Do until RS1.EOF
                IF LSTMID<>RS1("MID") THEN
                    ncount=ncount+1
                    IF RS1("test_id") = "2" THEN
                        course="Short"
                    ELSE
                        course="Long"   
                    END IF

                    Set RS0 = DB1.Execute ("SELECT * FROM members WHERE ID = '"& RS1("MID") &"'")  
                        Do until RS0.EOF
                    IF RS0("mtype") = "G" THEN
                        mt="Guest"
                    ELSE
                        mt="Member" 
                    END IF


    %>  
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 150"><%=mt%></td>
                            <td style="width: 250"><%=RS0("fname")%></td>
                            <td style="width: 250"><%=RS0("lname")%></td>
                            <td style="width: 250"><%=RS0("address1")%></td>
                            <td style="width: 120"><%=RS0("lot")%></td>
                            <td style="width: 120"><%=RS0("section")%></td>
                            <td style="width: 120"><%=course%></td>
                            <td class="style1" style="width: 120"><%=RS1("VBcustID")%></td>
                            <td class="style1" style="width: 120"><%=RS1("tottesttime")%></td>
                            <td class="style1" style="width: 120"><%=FormatPercent(RS1("grade"),0)%></td>
                            <td class="style1" style="width: 120"><%=RS1("passfail")%></td>
                        </tr>
            <%          
                        RS0.MoveNext
                        loop
                    RS0.Close

                    tottimes=1
                    LSTMID=RS1("MID")
                    ELSE
                        tottimes=tottimes+1
                    END IF
                RS1.MoveNext
            loop
        RS1.Close
    DB1.Close       
%>
    </table>
```

Comment: This appears to be classic ASP, based on the syntax and file extensions? Why did you tag this as ASP.NET? They're completely separate technologies.

Comment: I clicked the wrong option. As far as I can tell there isn't an existing tag for "classic ASP" or just ASP.

Comment: Yes, there is. I have added it to your question.

Comment: This looks completely wrong, why is there a nested loop? Surely the two queries should be joined, I imagine this is full of errors and really a [mcve] that people are going to able to help you with.

Comment: Get rid of Response.ContentType and make sure the script does the right output in browser. When it does work, add Response.ContentType and Response.AddHeader again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this at the top of your page

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=whatever-you-want-to-call-it.xls"
%>
```

I should add that if you're using Chrome it will ask you for loads of permissions before it launches the file in Excel

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried this before. On Chrome I get a "waiting for www.....org" message and then nothing happens.

On IE it just says "Downloading from site" and then an error message that says:

Comment: On IE it just says "Downloading from site" and then an error message that says:
Microsoft Excel cannot access file...There are several possible reasons.
The file name or path does not exist
The file is being used by another program
The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Comment: I think before they even to download it as a csv they need to try running it as HTML and fix the obvious code problems.

Comment: @LOWACommunications check if the MIME type exists on the IIS server, you must add it before you serve any content.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't solve the original problem, but I found a workaround. The site has a search engine with a three character minimum and I found that if I put in three underscores (SQL wildcards) then I could pull up all the info that I need onto the search results page and I could then copy and paste into excel.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i use datatable export to ms excel

try these pages.

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html